# is it valid to delete a class instance through its member variable?

Tags: android, c++, ios

Ok so I am trying to see if deleting a class through its member variable is safe? The member variable has a pointer to its containing class. This crashes on android after m_objectPtr->OnDestroy(); gets called. It works on IOS I was told by a co-worker. I was wondering if this code is valid.

```
class Object;
class ValueObject;
class SomeManager;

class DataInterface
{
public:
    virtual void OnDestroy(const ValueObject* value,void* data) = 0;
};

class destroyDelegate : public DataInterface
{
public:
    destroyDelegate(Object* obj) : m_objectPtr(obj)
    {
    }

    //...
    virtual void OnDestroy(const ValueObject* value,void* data)
    {
        m_objectPtr->OnDestroy();
    }
private:
    Object* m_objectPtr;
};

class Object
{
public:
    Object(SomeManager* manager,ValueObject* value) : 
    m_manager(manager), m_value(value), m_delegateObject(this)
    {
        // m_value calls OnDestroy when its being deleted. assume m_value is ref counted
        m_value->setDestroyCallBack(&m_delegateObject);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        m_manager->Destroy(this); // deletes this class and removes it from its std::list
    }
private:
    SomeManager* m_manager;
    ValueObject* m_value;
    destroyDelegate m_delegateObject;
};

// now some where in code m_value dies and calls on its member variable that inherits 
// DataInterface OnDestroy which chains down to deleting Object.
```

Comment: that should be fine so long as you don't use the *this* after it's deleted.  it looks like you're not, so it's ok.

Comment: why is it tagged as android?

Comment: @BunnyRabbit probably using the ndk

Comment: Yes this code, well code that is the same gets compiled using ndk-r8b/ndk-r8d and IOS 5-6.1. The code crashes on Android with a SIGSEGV violation 0x0000. It might be more factors to look into on this code. I was wondering was it valid since when Object is destroyed, the m_delegate is no longer valid and it is still in its OnDestroy function.

Comment: @user1739595 it should be, so long as it doesn't reference anything attached to `this` (i.e. it should be able to cleanly exit). This was a common error in many COM `IUnknown::Release()` implementations including reputable commercial ISVs code. They all-too-often coded it as `{ if (--m_dwRefCount == 0) delete this; return m_dwRefCount; }` Ah.. good times.